# How do I disable my smartchatbox from overlapping my fixed top navbar?

Tags: javascript, html, chat

[htttp://www.famebyname.us/chat.html](http://www.famebyname.us/chat.html)

Any help would be appreciated. The title of this question says it all. Just shrink your browser, scroll down, and you will see what I mean.

Comment: You may put the code here, if you really wish to get some help :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a z-index to the `#nav`:

```
z-index: 1;
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. This is my newest template style.